# No property consultancy found for type Consultancy! Traversed path: Consultant.consultancy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot application. I have the following models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "consultant")
public class Consultant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_generator",
            sequenceName = "id_sequence",
            initialValue = 1
    )
    private Long consultant_id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_first_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_last_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_phone;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean consultant_is_admin;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "consultancy_id", nullable = false)
    private Consultancy consultancy;

    public Consultant(){}

    public Consultant(String consultant_first_name, String consultant_last_name, String consultant_phone, String consultant_email, String consultant_password, boolean consultant_is_admin, Consultancy consultancy) {
        this.consultant_first_name = consultant_first_name;
        this.consultant_last_name = consultant_last_name;
        this.consultant_phone = consultant_phone;
        this.consultant_email = consultant_email;
        this.consultant_password = consultant_password;
        this.consultant_is_admin = consultant_is_admin;
        this.consultancy = consultancy;
    }

    public Long getConsultant_id() {
        return consultant_id;
    }

    public void setConsultant_id(Long consultant_id) {
        this.consultant_id = consultant_id;
    }

    public String getConsultant_first_name() {
        return consultant_first_name;
    }

    public void setConsultant_first_name(String consultant_first_name) {
        this.consultant_first_name = consultant_first_name;
    }

    public String getConsultant_last_name() {
        return consultant_last_name;
    }

    public void setConsultant_last_name(String consultant_last_name) {
        this.consultant_last_name = consultant_last_name;
    }

    public String getConsultant_phone() {
        return consultant_phone;
    }

    public void setConsultant_phone(String consultant_phone) {
        this.consultant_phone = consultant_phone;
    }

    public String getConsultant_email() {
        return consultant_email;
    }

    public void setConsultant_email(String consultant_email) {
        this.consultant_email = consultant_email;
    }

    public String getConsultant_password() {
        return consultant_password;
    }

    public void setConsultant_password(String consultant_password) {
        this.consultant_password = consultant_password;
    }

    public boolean isConsultant_is_admin() {
        return consultant_is_admin;
    }

    public void setConsultant_is_admin(boolean consultant_is_admin) {
        this.consultant_is_admin = consultant_is_admin;
    }

    public Consultancy getConsultancy() {
        return consultancy;
    }

    public void setConsultancy(Consultancy consultancy) {
        this.consultancy = consultancy;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="consultancy")
public class Consultancy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_generator",
            sequenceName = "id_sequence",
            initialValue = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long consultancy_id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_phone;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_website;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_address;



    public Consultancy() {
    }

    public Consultancy(String consultancy_name, String consultancy_email, String consultancy_phone, String consultancy_website, String consultancy_address) {
        this.consultancy_name = consultancy_name;
        this.consultancy_email = consultancy_email;
        this.consultancy_phone = consultancy_phone;
        this.consultancy_website = consultancy_website;
        this.consultancy_address = consultancy_address;
    }

    public Long getConsultancy_id() {
        return consultancy_id;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_id(Long consultancy_id) {
        this.consultancy_id = consultancy_id;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_name() {
        return consultancy_name;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_name(String consultancy_name) {
        this.consultancy_name = consultancy_name;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_email() {
        return consultancy_email;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_email(String consultancy_email) {
        this.consultancy_email = consultancy_email;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_phone() {
        return consultancy_phone;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_phone(String consultancy_phone) {
        this.consultancy_phone = consultancy_phone;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_website() {
        return consultancy_website;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_website(String consultancy_website) {
        this.consultancy_website = consultancy_website;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_address() {
        return consultancy_address;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_address(String consultancy_address) {
        this.consultancy_address = consultancy_address;
    }
}
```

I want to get `consultants` with a particular `consultancy_id`. I have my JpaRepository as follows:

```
public interface ConsultantRepository extends JpaRepository<Consultant, Long> {

    public List<Consultant> findAllByConsultancy_Consultancy_id(Long id);

}
```

When I run the application it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property consultancy found for type Consultancy! Traversed path: Consultant.consultancy.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:318) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

How can I map with the consultancy_id without having to write the entire query? I could make 2 calls, one to get the consultancy from ID and then passing the consultancy in the JPA function parameter but I want to do it in a single call to the database. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your eventual goal is to retrieve all consultants associated with a particular consultancy. That is a OneToMany relationship from the Consultancy side and a OneToOne relationship from the Consultancy side assuming that a specific consultant can be associated with a single Consultancy at a given point of time. Two things to achieve this.

1. Firstly, you ought to fix the Spring Data JPA conventions for the `consultancy_id` field. I have done this by naming the field as `consultancyId` and using a `@Column` name - see below.
2. Next you need to set up the JPA relationships in your entities correctly. You may or may not use a join table approach, but this is how I did it.

**The `Consultancy` entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="consultancy")
public class Consultancy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_generator",
            sequenceName = "id_sequence",
            initialValue = 1
    )
    @Column(name= "consultancy_id", nullable = false)
    private Long consultancyId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_phone;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_website;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultancy_address;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Consultant.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "consultant_consultancy_join_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "consultancy_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "consultant_id"))
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Consultant> consultants;


    public Consultancy() {
    }

    public Consultancy(String consultancy_name, String consultancy_email, String consultancy_phone, String consultancy_website, String consultancy_address) {
        this.consultancy_name = consultancy_name;
        this.consultancy_email = consultancy_email;
        this.consultancy_phone = consultancy_phone;
        this.consultancy_website = consultancy_website;
        this.consultancy_address = consultancy_address;
    }

    public Long getConsultancyId() {
        return consultancyId;
    }

    public void setConsultancyId(Long consultancyId) {
        this.consultancyId = consultancyId;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_name() {
        return consultancy_name;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_name(String consultancy_name) {
        this.consultancy_name = consultancy_name;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_email() {
        return consultancy_email;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_email(String consultancy_email) {
        this.consultancy_email = consultancy_email;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_phone() {
        return consultancy_phone;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_phone(String consultancy_phone) {
        this.consultancy_phone = consultancy_phone;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_website() {
        return consultancy_website;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_website(String consultancy_website) {
        this.consultancy_website = consultancy_website;
    }

    public String getConsultancy_address() {
        return consultancy_address;
    }

    public void setConsultancy_address(String consultancy_address) {
        this.consultancy_address = consultancy_address;
    }

    public Collection<Consultant> getConsultants() {
        return consultants;
    }

    public void setConsultants(Collection<Consultant> consultants) {
        this.consultants = consultants;
    }
}
```

**The `Consultant` entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "consultant")
public class Consultant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_generator",
            sequenceName = "id_sequence",
            initialValue = 1
    )
    private Long consultant_id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_first_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_last_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_phone;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String consultant_password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean consultant_is_admin;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Consultancy.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "consultant_consultancy_join_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "consultant_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "consultancy_id"))
    private Consultancy consultancy;

    public Consultant(){}

    public Consultant(String consultant_first_name, String consultant_last_name, String consultant_phone, String consultant_email, String consultant_password, boolean consultant_is_admin, Consultancy consultancy) {
        this.consultant_first_name = consultant_first_name;
        this.consultant_last_name = consultant_last_name;
        this.consultant_phone = consultant_phone;
        this.consultant_email = consultant_email;
        this.consultant_password = consultant_password;
        this.consultant_is_admin = consultant_is_admin;
        this.consultancy = consultancy;
    }

    public Long getConsultant_id() {
        return consultant_id;
    }

    public void setConsultant_id(Long consultant_id) {
        this.consultant_id = consultant_id;
    }

    public String getConsultant_first_name() {
        return consultant_first_name;
    }

    public void setConsultant_first_name(String consultant_first_name) {
        this.consultant_first_name = consultant_first_name;
    }

    public String getConsultant_last_name() {
        return consultant_last_name;
    }

    public void setConsultant_last_name(String consultant_last_name) {
        this.consultant_last_name = consultant_last_name;
    }

    public String getConsultant_phone() {
        return consultant_phone;
    }

    public void setConsultant_phone(String consultant_phone) {
        this.consultant_phone = consultant_phone;
    }

    public String getConsultant_email() {
        return consultant_email;
    }

    public void setConsultant_email(String consultant_email) {
        this.consultant_email = consultant_email;
    }

    public String getConsultant_password() {
        return consultant_password;
    }

    public void setConsultant_password(String consultant_password) {
        this.consultant_password = consultant_password;
    }

    public boolean isConsultant_is_admin() {
        return consultant_is_admin;
    }

    public void setConsultant_is_admin(boolean consultant_is_admin) {
        this.consultant_is_admin = consultant_is_admin;
    }

    public Consultancy getConsultancy() {
        return consultancy;
    }

    public void setConsultancy(Consultancy consultancy) {
        this.consultancy = consultancy;
    }
}
```

**The Database Schema**(I am using Derby dialect, choose the appropriate one for your DB):

```
-- Consultant table
create table consultant (
  consultant_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    consultant_first_name           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultant_last_name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultant_phone                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultant_email                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultant_password             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultant_is_admin             boolean     NOT NULL DEFAULT false
);

-- Consultancy table
create table consultancy (
  consultancy_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    consultancy_name           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultancy_email            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultancy_phone                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultancy_website                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    consultancy_address             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Join table
CREATE TABLE consultant_consultancy_join_table (
  consultant_id                    BIGINT                                       NOT NULL,
  consultancy_id                   BIGINT                                       NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_consultant_id FOREIGN KEY (consultant_id) REFERENCES consultant(consultant_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_consultancy_id FOREIGN KEY (consultancy_id) REFERENCES consultancy (consultancy_id)
);
```

**Some test data:**

```
insert into consultant (consultant_first_name, consultant_last_name, consultant_phone, consultant_email, consultant_password, consultant_is_admin) values
('John', 'Doe', '210-917-6789', 'john.doe@acme.com', 'work2eat', true),
('Jane', 'Doe', '210-867-7635', 'jane.doe@acme.com', 'work2eat', true);

insert into consultancy (consultancy_name, consultancy_email, consultancy_phone, consultancy_website, consultancy_address) values
('Acme Consultancy', 'info@acme.com', '210-902-8956', 'www.acme.com', '9910, Any Street, San Antonio, TX, 78210');

insert into consultant_consultancy_join_table(consultant_id, consultancy_id) values
(1,1),
(2,1);
```

**The `ConsultancyRepository` class:**

```
public interface ConsultancyRepository extends CrudRepository<Consultancy, Long> {

    Consultancy findByConsultancyId (Long consultancyId);
}
```

**A JUnit Test case:**

```
public class ConsultancyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConsultancyRepository consultancyRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllConsultants() {
        Consultancy consultancy = consultancyRepository.findByConsultancyId(1L);
        assertNotNull(consultancy);
        assertEquals(2, consultancy.getConsultants().size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I don't wish to use a join table as there is only one consultancy a consultant can be associated with. So according to my Database Schema design, there's a field called consultancy_id in the consultant table itself. and it is like one consultancy can be associated with many consultants so I put it as manyToOne relationship in the consultant entity, I might be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem.

```
public List<Consultant> findAllByConsultancy_Consultancy_id(Long id);
```

As per Spring data jpa if you want to find by property then that property should be present in your entity class.

So here `findAllByConsultancy_Consultancy_id` in this method JPA treats `Consultancy_Consultancy_id` like a field but it is not present so it gives error.

Change your method to

```
public List<Consultant> findAllByConsultancy_id(Long id);
```

and check.it should work.

NOTE : Always maintain standards and try to avoid using `consultant_first_name` but use `consultantFirstName` instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doing it this way gives the following error: `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Consultancy! Traversed path: Consultant.consultancy.`

Comment: try with public List<Consultant> findAllByConsultancyId(Long id); once.by removing hyphen and make Id uppercase.

Comment: It didn't work, looking at the error, the JPA takes the first word as the referred model and second word as the field in the model(i think the one in the database). Example findAllByModel_field. I assume the fieldname is referred to the one in database and not the one in the model.